# Dedekind sums + strange integral

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I need to write $\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$, where $f(x) = \# \Sigma_{pq} \cap (x, x+1)$ for $x \in [0, 1]$, where $$\Sigma_{pq} = \left \{ \frac{k}{p} + \frac{l}{q}:\ 1 \leq k \leq p-1, 1 \leq l \leq q-1 \right\}$$ ($p, q$ are coprime positive integers), using Dedekind sums: $s(p,q)$ and $s(q,p)$ where $s(p,q) = \sum_{j=0}^{q} \left( \left( \frac{j}{q} \right) \right) \left( \left(\frac{jp}{q} \right) \right)$, $((x)) = x - \lfloor x \rfloor - \frac{1}{2}$ for $x \not\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0$ for $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I don't know what to start with. Any ideas?

The only thing I've got now (but don't know if it helps) is:
$$\int_0^1 f(x)\, dx = \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \sum_{j=1}^{q-1} \int_0^1 \chi_{(x,x+1)}\left(\frac{i}{p} + \frac{j}{q}\right)\,dx$$

Comment: No. First of all, I really **want** those Dedekind sums to be there.
And which sum equals $\frac{(q-1)(p-1)}{2}$? That integral? As far as I know, it doesn't.

Comment: You are correct.  I made a mistake with a sign.

Comment: i've found this: [1](http://blog.felixbreuer.net/2011/08/30/visualising-numbers-part2.html), [2](http://www.new.dli.ernet.in/rawdataupload/upload/insa/INSA_1/20005b92_527.pdf), [3](http://gifted.hkedcity.net/Gifted/Download/notes/0607math2phase/advanced/06-11-4-11-18_dedekind%20sums.pdf). don't know yet if it's useful here but maybe...